# Hybris Backoffice Node customization

Tags: customization, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I need to add a node to Backoffice and display a screen with API response details. I have a Node1 and three child nodes, node1.1,node1.2 and node1,3. If the user clicks on node1.1 he should be able to see a screen with three sections where fields are loaded from API response. Attached is the image for reference. Please help in this. Also these fields must change with Success or Error response and connection test.[image]

Comment: Are those Hybris APIs? If you are using OCC, checkout the built-in Swagger, instead of customizing backoffice.

Comment: we have created our own API's..not using OCC.

Comment: I have created a custom node in backoffice and on click of the custom node, a page gets displayed which contains several information blocks that will be populated from the rest api created. I want to know as to what will be the steps to code in order to enable the call. I have already created the node and page needs to be prefilled with the information fetched from the rest api's. Please help on this.